# How do I drive an animation loop at 60fps with Dart and the web?

Tags: dart, dart-html

How do I drive an animation loop or game loop at 60fps in a Dart web application?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use `window.animationFrame`, the Future-based cousin of the traditional `window.requestAnimationFrame`.

Dart has been shifting to use [Future](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_async/Future.html) and [Stream](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_async/Stream.html) as more object-oriented ways to handle asynchronous operations. The callback-based (old 'n busted) `requestAnimationFrame` is replaced by the Future-based (new hotness) `animationFrame`.

Here is a sample:

```dart
import 'dart:html';

gameLoop(num delta) {
  // do stuff
  window.animationFrame.then(gameLoop);
}

void main() {
  window.animationFrame.then(gameLoop);
}
```

The signature of `animationFrame` looks like:

```dart
Future<num> animationFrame();
```

Notice how `animationFrame` returns a Future that completes with a `num`, which holds a "high performance timer" similar to `window.performance.now()`. The `num` is a monotonically increasing delta between now and when the page started. It has microsecond resolution.

The Future completes right before the browser is about the draw the page. Update the state of your world and draw everything when this Future completes.

You must request a new Future from animationFrame on every frame, if you want the animation or loop to continue. In this example, `gameLoop()` registers to be notified on the next animation frame.

BTW there is a pub package named [game_loop](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/game_loop), which you might find useful.

Comment: That game_loop link gives a 404

Comment: How is requestAnimationFrame old 'n busted? Looking at the source the Future based animationFrame creates a completer to be that is triggered by using the original (old 'n busted) requestAnimationFrame callback?

Comment: @paulecoyote I don't believe Seth meant requestAnimationFrame is old 'n busted; but rather the idea of using callbacks; Futures are a much nicer API.