# How do I slow down the game loop in the game_loop package

Tags: dart, game-loop

I am using the `game_loop` pub package to handle my eventloop. The problem is that it updates way too often. I don't need to update or redraw that often, and input key repetition is also too fast. I do not know much about eventloops or browser redraws, so I might think of it the wrong way, but is there a way to slow the loop down?

Comment: I think you should always draw as fast as possible. What do you mean by input key repetition?

Comment: I think the input key repetition is an operating system setting.

Answer (score 1):

Run heavy tasks in the separate `Isolate` while keeping game loop as lightweight as possible. The game loop should be implemented with  `window.animationFrame`. [How do I drive an animation loop at 60fps with Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753170/how-do-i-drive-an-animation-loop-at-60fps-with-dart) You should learn all about [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame)  - it's the key to the smooth animations.

And your game logic speed should not depend on the browser FPS(Frames Per Second) use scheduler instead [Does Dart have a scheduler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15848214/does-dart-have-a-scheduler/15854423#15854423)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a timer and avoid adding an onUpdate or onRender handler to your GameLoop instance:

```dart
//timer fires 20 times per second, as an example
gameLoop.addTimer(render,0.05,periodic: true);

...
...
render(GameLoopTimer timer)
{
    //draw or update code here
}
```